# Sequence problem : Find $|a_1|$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

> Given a sequence such that
> $$a_1a_2=1\ ; \  a_2a_3=2 \  ; \  a_3a_4=3  \ ; \ \dots$$ and
> $$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}=1$$
> find $|a_1|$.

My attempts :

We can deduce from this $a_1a_2=1 \  ; \  a_2a_3=2 \  ; \  a_3a_4=3  \ ; \ \dots$ that :
$$\prod_{n=k}^{n+1} a_n=n$$
Thus :
$$\begin{align}a_n \times a_{n+1}&=n \\ a_{n+1}&=\frac{n}{a_n} \end{align}$$
Therefore :
$$\begin{align} \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}&=\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{a_n}{\frac{n}{a_n}} \\ &=\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{a_n^2}{n} \\&=1 \end{align} $$
Is this can lead us to say that :
$$\begin{align} |a_n^2|&\sim n \\ |a_n|&\sim \sqrt{n} \end{align} $$
If this is true we can say that :
$$|a_n| =1$$
But I don't know if this is true or not. Any tips or hints ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: The equivalence is for large $n$, with a choice of error $\varepsilon >0$. This is no use to try to compute an exact  value at $n=1$ with it.

Comment: @DIdier_ Yeah, That's why I thought that it's false ! I used btw the definiton and I didn't solved it :'( !

Comment: to me, it seems like there is no solution as many sequences can have the asymptotic behavior $\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}\to 1$ with prescribed values of $a_1a_2$, $a_2a_4$ and $a_3a_4$.

Comment: Why do you have $|a_1|$? Do you suspect it can be negative?

Comment: @Alex ,  that was the given question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may notice that a celebrated sequence has very similar properties: by defining
$$ I_n = \int_{0}^{\pi/2}\left(\sin \theta\right)^n\,d\theta $$
we have
$$ I_{2n} = \frac{\pi}{2\cdot 4^n}\binom{2n}{n},\qquad I_{2n+1}=\frac{4^n}{(2n+1)\binom{2n}{n}} $$
by integration by parts. $\{I_n\}_{n\geq 1}$ is obviously decreasing to zero and fulfills $ I_n I_{n+1} = \frac{\pi}{2(n+1)}$.
 Moreover, by Euler's Beta function (or just from the previous line) we have
$$ I_n = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}\,\Gamma\left(\frac{n+1}{2}\right)}{2\,\Gamma\left(\frac{n+2}{2}\right)}\sim\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2n}}. $$

It follows that the sequence
$$ a_n = \frac{\sqrt{\pi/2}}{\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\left(\sin\theta\right)^{n-1}\,d\theta} $$
meets the hypothesis of our problem.
 Provided that the solution is unique, this proves $a_1=\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}$ without invoking Stirling's approximation.

Comment: $I_n$ is used in the proof of the [Wallis product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallis_product) formula - without even using Euler's Beta function.

Answer (score 6):

We find $a_1/a_3=1/2$, $a_1a_4=1\cdot3/2$, $a_1/a_5=1\cdot3/(2\cdot4)$.
By induction, it one shows that
$$a_1a_{2n}=\frac{1\cdot3\cdot\dots\cdot(2n-1)}{2\cdot4\cdot\dots\cdot(2n-2)}$$
for integer $n\geq2$, whereas
$$a_1/a_{2n+1}=\frac{1\cdot3\cdot\dots\cdot(2n-1)}{2\cdot4\cdot\dots\cdot(2n)}$$
for integers $n\geq1$.

Since $a_{2n}/a_{2n+1}\to1$ by assumption, we have
$$a_1^2=\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{(1\cdot3\cdot\dots\cdot(2n-1))^2}
    {(2\cdot4\cdot\dots\cdot(2n-2))^2(2n)}=
    \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(2n-1)!^2}{2^{4n-3}(n-1)!^4n}=
    \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(2n)!^2n}{2^{4n-1}n!^4}.$$
A calculation using Stirling's formula shows that
$a_1^2=2/\pi$ and hence 
$$|a_1|=\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}.$$

**Edit:** a) Let me complete the solution by a calculation of the limit using Stirling's formula twice:
$$\begin{array}{rcl}2\log((2n)!)-4\log(n!)-(4n-1)\log2+\log n&
=&2\left[(2n+\frac12)(\log n+\log2)-2n+\frac12\log(2\pi)\right]\\
&&-4\left[(n+\frac12)\log n-n+\frac12\log(2\pi)\right]\\
&&+\log n-(4n-1)\log2+ O(\frac1n)\\
&=&2\log 2-\log(2\pi)+O(\frac1n)\to\log(2/\pi).\end{array}$$

b) The solution also works in the complex domain. Then we obtain $a_1=\pm\sqrt{\frac2\pi}$ which is more precise in the complex domain.

c) For arbitrary $a_1$, the solution shows that
$$\frac{a_{2n}}{a_{2n+1}}\to\frac2{\pi a_1^2}.$$
As $\frac{a_{2n}}{a_{2n+2}}=\frac{2n}{2n+1}\to1$, this implies that
$\frac{a_{2n+1}}{a_{2n+2}}\to\frac{\pi a_1^2}2.$
Therefore $a_n/a_{n+1}\to1$ if and only if $a_1^2=2/\pi$.

d) One can also write using the first two formulas of the solution and $a_{2n+2}/a_{2n+1}\to1$
$$a_1^2=\lim_{n\to\infty}a_1^2\frac{a_{2n+2}}{a_{2n+1}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(1\cdot3\cdot\dots\cdot(2n-1))^2(2n+1)}
    {(2\cdot4\cdot\dots\cdot(2n-2)(2n))^2}=\frac{1\cdot3}{2^2}\cdot
    \frac{3\cdot5}{4^2}\cdots=\frac2\pi$$
by the [Wallis product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallis_product).

Comment: Thank you, this is a great answer !

Answer (score 2):

Since $a_{n+1} = n/a_n$ the sequence $a_n$ is fully determined from the starting value $a_1$.

In fact it turns out that

> $$a_n = \frac{n-1}{a_{n-1}} =\frac{n-1}{n-2} a_{n-2} = \cdots = \frac{(n-1)!!}{(n-2)!!} a_1^{(-1)^{n+1}}$$

Where $N!!$ denotes the [semifactorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_factorial). From this you get that

> $$\frac{a_{n}}{a_{n+1}} = \frac{((n-1)!!)^2}{(n-2)!! n !!} (a_1)^{2(-1)^{n+1}}$$

In order to analyze asymptotic behaviour you may want distinguish even and odd $n$

$$\frac{a_{2n}}{a_{2n+1}} = \frac{((2n-1)!!)^2}{(2n)!!(2n-2)!!} a_1^{-2} = \left(\frac{(2n-1)!!}{(2n)!!}\right)^2 \frac{2n}{a_1^2} = \left(\frac{(2n)!}{(2n )!!^2}\right)^2\frac{2n}{a_1^2}$$

$$\frac{a_{2n+1}}{a_{2n+2}} = \frac{((2n)!!)^2}{(2n+1)!!(2n-1)!!} a_1^{2} = \left(\frac{(2n)!!}{(2n-1)!!}\right)^2 \frac{a_1^2}{2n+1} = \left(\frac{(2 n)!!^2}{(2n)!}\right)^2\frac{a_1^2}{2n+1}$$

Passing to logarithms you get

$$\log\left(\frac{a_{2n}}{a_{2n+1}}\right) = 2 \big( \log( (2n)! ) - 2\log( (2n)!!) \big) +\log(2n) - 2\log(a_1)$$

$$\log\left(\frac{a_{2n+1}}{a_{2n}}\right) = 2 \big( 2\log( (2n)!!) - \log((2n)!)\big) - \log(2n+1) + 2\log(a_1)$$

Recall the [Stirling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) approximation

$$\log(n!)=n\log(n)-n+\frac{1}{2} \log(n) + \log(\sqrt{2\pi}) +o(1)$$

from this you get approximations

$$\log((2n)!!) = \log(2^n n!) = n\log(n) + (\log(2)-1) n + \frac{1}{2} \log(n) + \log(\sqrt{2\pi}) +o(1) $$

$$\log((2n)!) = 2n \log(n) + (2\log(2)-2) n + \frac{1}{2} \log(n) + \log(2\sqrt{\pi})+o(1)$$

Subtracting you have $2\log((2n)!!) - \log((2n)!) = \frac{1}{2} \log(n) + \log( \sqrt{\pi}) +o(1)$, so

$$\log\left(\frac{a_{2n}}{a_{2n+1}}\right) = \log(2) - \log(\pi) -2 \log(a_1) +o(1)$$

$$\log\left(\frac{a_{2n+1}}{a_{2n}}\right) = \log(\pi) - \log(2) + 2\log(a_1) +o(1)$$

Hence there is a value of $a_1$ for which $a_n/a_{n+1} \to 1$ and it has to satisfy $2\log(a_1)= \log(2/\pi)$, that is $a_1= \sqrt{2/\pi}$.

Comment: For me this should be the right answer, 1 upvote from me !